# Find in closed form.$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\ln(1+\cos(x))}{1+\sin^2(x)}\right)\cos(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Find in closed form .
$\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\ln(1+\cos(x))}{1+\sin^2(x)}\right)\cos(x)dx$
My work 
We put $t=\cos(x)$ we find $\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\ln(1+\cos(x))}{1+\sin^2(x)}\right)\cos(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2-n}{2})+\frac{3}{4}\eta(1)-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2+3n}$
But :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2-n}{2})=?$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2+3n}$

Where $\eta(s)$is eta function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I did not check your calculations.*

$$\frac{1}{2n^2+3n}=\frac{1}{3 n}-\frac{2}{3 (2 n+3)}$$

$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{2n^2+3n}=\frac{1}{3}H_p-\frac{1}{3} \left(\psi \left(p+\frac{5}{2}\right)-\psi
  \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)$$Using asymptotics
$$S_p=\left(\frac{8}{9}-\frac{2 \log (2)}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
On the other side
$$T_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}(-1)^n\frac{ B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}{n}$$ is a nice monster in terms of hypergeometric function but its limit is simply
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}$$